conditional variable types in C# interop depending on OS and Architecture
C# Interop question.
i have a C++ library that uses a struct:
struct CPPSTRUCT
{
    long v1;
    short v2;
    long v3;
}

In C#, I have a corresponding structure:
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MANAGEDSTRUCT
{ 
    public int v1;
    public short v2;
    public int v3;
}

It works as long as C++ library is built for Windows x64, however, it breaks when same library is built for Linux x64.  The reason for it breaking, is because C++ length of long is 4 bytes in Win x64 but is 8 bytes in Linux x64: changing int types in MANAGEDSTRUCT to long types fixes the issue for linux x64, but breaks it for windows x64.
Another issue is that when setting/getting the values for v1 and v3 in MANAGEDSTRUCT may become conditional as well.
I am looking for the best C# appropriate way to conditionally declare variable types/Marshall it depending on OS/Architecture, so that application consuming the C++ library can target multiple platforms without having to worry about types, and being able to set values in MANAGEDSSTRUCT by the client.
Thank you!

The issue is likely to be alignment rather than type size. If this is intended to be an external API, I'd change the C++ code (if you can) to be pedantic about type sizes and memory alignment.

To augment what @JeremyLakeman has pointed out, that's a terribly defined C structure. Depending on compiler, on machine architecture, and on the packing and alignment settings, the in memory layout of that structure can change (even the member sizes can change (long may be 4 or 8 bytes). Are you sure that's what your C (/C++) structure looks like. Back when I was a C (and later C++) dev, I quickly learned to set up structure definitions with packing and alignment in mind

Thank you:  changing c++ application isnt goin got be easy, but not impossible, and while this is obviously a simplification for the purposes of illustration, C++ struct i am dealing with kind of does look like that.  Curious: how would c++ struct definition have to change to be more platform agnostic/pedantic about types?

@concentriq Using the types in , v1 and v3 would use int32_t, and v2 would use int16_t. This way v1 and v3 will always be 32 bits (fixed size of int in C#), v2 would always be 16 bits (fixed size of short in C#)

Ah, but, that will get laid out differently on machines (or compiler settings) that require 32 or 64 bit alignment compared to traditional lax x86 settings

Not sure it will work, but you can try global types alias as following (pseudocode)
#if Windows
    global using NativeLong = System.Int32; //int
#elseif Linux
    global using NativeLong = System.Int64; //long
#endif

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MANAGEDSTRUCT
{ 
    public NativeLong v1;
    public short v2;
    public NativeLong v3;
}

Then you can use this NativeLong in all the codebase.
Specs for global type alias are here
P.S. Please review the comments under the question (especially by @Flydog57 and @ipodtouch0218 - looks like it is better approach shown there)

What about creating different conficurations for different platforms and defining an appropriate constants, then using conditional directives in your code and abstractiving the interop detials?
Like so (a crude example)
    #if LINUX64
    
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MANAGEDSTRUCT
    { 
        public long v1;
        public short v2;
        public long v3;
    }
    
    #else
    
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MANAGEDSTRUCT
    { 
        public int v1;
        public short v2;
        public int v3;
    }
    
    #endif
    
    public int DoSomething(int v1, short v2, int v3)
    {
        MANAGEDSTRUCT s = new MANAGEDSTRUCT();
        s.v1 = v1;
        s.v2 = v2;
        s.v3 = v3;
        // Do interop stuff
        return (int)s.v1;  // I assume that the value will fit in 4 bytes since it work under Windows
    }

P.S.
Is the C++ library developed by you/your collegues? If yes, I would suggest rewriting it to specify the size of the struct fields in a platform independent manner (int32_t or int64_t)
